# The Case of the Missing Kitten (Part 2)

Tags: word, english

After solving [the kidnapper's riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18421/the-case-of-the-missing-kitten-part-1), you realize that you have no clue how to get in touch with him. You wait until the end of the specified fortnight, and sure enough, you receive a phone call. "I solved your riddle," you say, triumphantly.

The only response is, "Answer?"

You provide the solution, and the kidnapper says, "Good. You solved it. Time to get your precious Geronimo back. Open your door; you'll see another note for you."

As you open the door, you find another note. It reads:

---

Congratulations,

You solved the riddle within the fortnight, and your cat will live to see another week (or two, if you're quick). Before you can get him back, we have to meet. Unfortunately, you don't know how to find me, and I won't come to you. Figure out the next letter in each sequence, then unscramble to find the solution. Inspired by [VictorHenry](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18363/a-quindectet-of-letter-sequences).

Where am I?

1. S, P, S, M, T, ?
2. A, B, B, F, G, L, M, ?
3. W, A, J, M, M, ?
4. V, M, K, K, E, E, ?
5. F, M, M, B, B, E, ?
6. S, M, H, D, W, M, ?
7. C, T, F, N, I, ?
8. R, C, U, C, B, A, ?
9. W, B, S, K, N, ?
10. A, T, J, A, F, ?
11. N, U, S, J, M, ?
12. P, A, I, S, ?
13. T, T, T, F, F, S, S, E, ?
14. E, G, D, S, F, L, ?

I feel nice, so I'll start you out with one letter given: C.

Love, Al.

Hint 1:

> Some of these sequences are worldly knowledge, such as oldest cities, fastest rivers, etc. Others are only found between the pages of a novel.

Edit:

> Nearly a year has passed, you can only hope your cat is still alive. If this question regains some traction I think it might be nice for someone to compile the existing (and future) answers into one or make a community answer.

Comment: Is this going to be a [tag:trivia]-worthy question?

Comment: @BaileyM I guess it could be. I'm quite new to puzzling, so I don't know what qualifies as a trivia-worthy question. I can say that all of the answers are publicly available, but more common than not.

Comment: Status report: 3, 4, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13 down; 1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10, 14 to go.

Comment: @randal'thor soon to be Mr. 25k?

Comment: @Moose Well, one can hope :-) but that'll take me 4 days at the very least, and my rate isn't what it used to be!

Comment: Are you sure the 6th letter shouldn't be L in #14?

Comment: Oh, it definitely should! My mistake

Comment: kitty gonna die

Comment: Do you maybe have another small hint you could give us?

Comment: @DooplissForce This is a little embarrassing but I honestly forgot what the answers were; I had them written down but they were on an old drive that I lost the data on =/. If I recall correctly, many of them were factual stuff about the world

Comment: Ah lol! I'll have a look and see if I can get any of them, then :)

Comment: Yeah, that's why I suggested maybe a community wiki, because I'm interested in learning what I was thinking :P

Answer (score 5):

11. N, U, S, J, M, ?

> **E**: the planets in reverse order
>  **N**eptune, **U**ranus, **S**aturn, **J**upiter, **M**ars, **E**arth

3. W, A, J, M, M, ?

> **A**: the first six US Presidents
>  **W**ashington, **A**dams, **J**efferson, **M**adison, **M**onroe, **A**dams

Comment: Two down, after @Geobits added his two cents

Comment: I'll add that 13 should be **N** for *ninety*.

Comment: @Geobits might as well make your own partial answer, since his is only one sequence thus far.

Comment: True, but I don't really plan on doing any others. That one just stuck out to me as I was skimming the list. It's free for anyone to grab, no worries.

Comment: Personally I'd rather it be left for someone to find for themeselves then.

Answer (score 5):

7. C, T, F, N, I, ?

> **P**: US states by population. **C**alifornia, **T**exas, **F**lorida, **N**ew York, **I**llinois, **P**ennsylvania

Answer (score 5):

## 14:

> **C**. Based on the book titles from the Wheel of Time series: The **E**ye of the World, The **G**reat Hunt, The **D**ragon Reborn (*hello everyone!*), The **S**hadow Rising, The **F**ires of Heaven, Lord of **C**haos, A **C**rown of Swords.

Comment: I had hoped you'd get that one :P. I was writing this thinking *Man, I bet rand al'thor is the only person besides me to know the series. If he doesn't see this, everyone else is hosed.* (btw my name used to be Jon Snow, we had a conversation about WoT like a month and a half ago).

Comment: @Moose Ah, right! So in your new incarnation you no longer know nothing? ;-) And we're not the only WoT fans here; chasly from UK knows it too, and check [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10399/double-whammy-murder-case-what-happened/10401#comment34571_10401) out!

Comment: it's refreshing to find others. And yes, I now do know things

Answer (score 4):

8. R, C, U, C, B, A, ?

> **I**: world countries by land area. **R**ussia, **C**anada, **U**nited States, **C**hina, **B**razil, **A**ustralia, **I**ndia

12. P, A, I, S, ?

> **A**: bodies of water by size. **P**acific Ocean, **A**tlantic Ocean, **I**ndian Ocean, **S**outhern Ocean, **A**rctic Ocean

Comment: Should I have made these harder?

Answer (score 4):

4. V M K K E E

> the seven summits: Vinson, McKinley, Kilimanjaro, Kosciuszko, Everest, Elbrus, **Aconcagua**

13. T T T F F S S E

> Counting by tens: Ten Twenty Thirty Forty Fifty Sixty Seventy Eighty **Ninety**

Comment: Note: I didn't read comments to notice Geobits answered 13 first... credit for that goes to him.

Comment: I can't figure out the reason for the order of the seven summits.. if someone has a better idea, don't hesitate to post it.

Comment: Reverse alphabetical?

Comment: @arth guess that works

Answer (score 4):

6. S, M, H, D, W, M, ?

> Y - the sequence is units of time increasing in length (second, minute, hour, day, week, month, year)

Answer (score 3):

Making a community wiki answer to collect what we have so far, and to get some fresh eyes on this one.

1. S, P, S, M, T, ?

> Unsolved

2. A, B, B, F, G, L, M, ?

> Unsolved

3. W, A, J, M, M, ?

> **A**
>  The US Presidents in order: Washington, Adams, Jefferson, Madison, Monroe, **A**dams (@dennisdeems)

4. V, M, K, K, E, E, ?

> **A**
>  The seven summits: Vinson, McKinley, Kilimanjaro, Kosciuszko, Everest, Elbrus, **A**concagua  (@kaine)

5. F, M, M, B, B, E, ?

> Unsolved

6. S, M, H, D, W, M, ?

> **Y**
>  Units of time increasing in length (second, minute, hour, day, week, month, **y**ear) (@Pete)

7. C, T, F, N, I, ?

> **P**
>  US states by population. California, Texas, Florida, New York, Illinois, **P**ennsylvania (@Somo145)

8. R, C, U, C, B, A, ?

> **I**
>  World countries by land area. Russia, Canada, United States, China, Brazil, Australia, **I**ndia  (@Bailey M)

9. W, B, S, K, N, ?

> Unsolved

10. A, T, J, A, F, ?

> Unsolved

11. N, U, S, J, M, ?

> **E**
>  The planets in reverse order: Neptune, Uranus, Saturn, Jupiter, Mars, **E**arth (@dennisdeems)

12. P, A, I, S, ?

> **A**
>  Bodies of water by size. Pacific Ocean, Atlantic Ocean, Indian Ocean, Southern Ocean, **A**rctic Ocean (@Bailey M)

13. T, T, T, F, F, S, S, E, ?

> **N**
>  Counting by tens: Ten Twenty Thirty Forty Fifty Sixty Seventy Eighty **N**inety (@kaine)

14. E, G, D, S, F, L, ?

> **C**
>  Based on the book titles from the Wheel of Time series: The Eye of the World, The Great Hunt, The Dragon Reborn (hello everyone!), The Shadow Rising, The Fires of Heaven, Lord of Chaos, A **C**rown of Swords.

15. **C** (given for free).

> The (most likely) task is now to find a place/landmark described by a 15-letter anagram (of which we only know 10 letters) using
>  AAACCEINPY?????

Comment: This would be so much easier if I hadn't lost the answers. Thanks for making this